# Phantom: WalletSignTransactionError: Something went wrong

Tags: phantomjs, solana-web3js

A message is created and the user signs it.

```js
const anchorWallet = useAnchorWallet();

const createLoginSignature = async () => {
    if (!anchorWallet) return;

    const message = "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";

    const tx = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(message, "base64"));

    const signTx = await anchorWallet.signTransaction(tx);

    const signedData = signTx.serialize().toString("base64");

    return signedData;
};
```

This code works in localhost.

But I also get some errors in production.

Error description: `Phantom - RPC Error: Something went wrong. {code: -32603, message: 'Something went wrong.'}`

Localhost(success)
[image: Localhost Phantom Popup]
Production(failure)
[image: Product Phantom Popup]

Why do I encounter such an error?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

File: `next.config.js` 
Remove: `swcMinify: true`

It works for me